# Laravel - Trying to get property 'employee_code' of non-object

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have this function in the Controller:

```
        $linemanager                    = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first()->line_manager_id;
        $linemanagerid                  = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('employee_code')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager)->first()->employee_code;
        $linemanageruserid              = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager)->first();  
        $linemanageruserids             = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('employee_code', $linemanageruserid->line_manager_id)->first();
        $employeelinemanagerid          = $linemanageruserids->employee_code;
```

When I submitted I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'employee_code' of non-object

This code is underline:

> $employeelinemanagerid          = $linemanageruserids->employee_code;

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: `first` can return a single record or `null` ... so the query on the previous line to the error did NOT return a result

Comment: Add this line of code `dd($linemanageruserids)` before the error given line and share your output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'first()' may get null if there is no data match the where you specified ...

just break this:

```
  $linemanagerid = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('employee_code')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager)->first()->employee_code;
```

to:

```
$value=DB::table('hr_employees')->select('employee_code')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager)->first();
if($value!=null)  $linemanagerid=$value->->employee_code;
```

note: you can merge 'first' with 'where' using 'firstWhere'

```
$value=DB::table('hr_employees')->select('employee_code')->firstWhere('line_manager_id', $linemanager);
```